# How is this an indefinite matrix.

Tags: matrices, positive-definite

$$\begin{pmatrix}2 &-6\\
-6 &4\end{pmatrix}$$

Can you please tell me how the above $2\times2$ matrix is indefinite? I thought the first principle leading minor is $2>0$, and the second is ${8-(-36)}=44>0$. So it should be positive definite?

Comment: it should be 2 -6 in the first row, -6 4 in the second row

Answer (score 0):

You've miscalculated the second leading minor - it should be $2 \times 4 - (-6)\times(-6) = 8 - 36 = -28$

Comment: sorry that was careless on my part.

Answer (score 0):

One clear way to show that it's not positive definite is to find a vector such that the corresponding outer product is negative. For instance,
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 2&-6 \\ -6&4 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = -6,$$
which is certainly negative.

As for what's wrong with your calculation: $(-6)^2 = 36$, not $-36$.

Comment: sorry that was careless.